Question on distinguishing similar words: שׂכל ,בין ,חכם ,ידע
How does one distinguish between שׂכל, בין, חכם, ידע?
And their respective nouns: שֶׂכֶל, בִּינָה, חָכְמָה, מַדָע, דַּעַת
When comparing the lexicons Dictionary of Classical Hebrew and HALOT I see that they give different glosses for each context, but those lexicons never seem to give the true basic meaning of each word that stands behind every occurrence. So it becomes confusing as בין and שׂכל are both said to mean "to understand," or שׂכל and חכם are said to both mean "be wise." But what exactly is the difference? Moreover, I get the feeling מַדָע is something more specific than דַּעַת.
It seems that there is room for more precision in understanding these words than that which modern lexicons for English readers can provide. Especially considering a passage like Daniel 1:4:

יְלָדִ֣ים אֲשֶׁ֣ר אֵֽין־בָּהֶ֣ם כָּל־מְאוּם וְטוֹבֵ֨י מַרְאֶ֜ה וּמַשְׂכִּילִ֣ים בְּכָל־חָכְמָ֗ה וְיֹ֤דְעֵי דַ֨עַת֙ וּמְבִינֵ֣י מַדָּ֔ע וַאֲשֶׁר֙ כֹּ֣חַ בָּהֶ֔ם לַעֲמֹ֖ד בְּהֵיכַ֣ל הַמֶּ֑לֶךְ וּֽלֲלַמְּדָ֥ם סֵ֖פֶר וּלְשׁ֥וֹן כַּשְׂדִּֽים׃

Which has all of these terms in close proximity. I would greatly appreciate any help with these words specifically, or suggested resources that try to more precisely delineate Hebrew synonyms.
Thank you!

This is a question I've asked all my life and never got a straight answer, or gotten contradictory answers. Therefore my current approach is that on the level of pshat, it is context and perush based (noting the rough definitions you've brought). When you start studying deeper Torah, you'll find very rigorous definitions. I am inclined to give the definitions of these 4 shorashim according to Chabad Chassidut because they are the Kabbalistic definitions, and are all very clear and distinct.

A better English translation for שכל would be intellect as a noun. As a verb it would be להשכיל meaning to intellectualize. The noun for understanding is הבנה. While verb is מבין from להבין. The word for wisdom is חכמה, while חכם means an individual who is wise. This is often translated in English as “Sage”. While the verb לחכם means “to be wise”.

בינה is the function of processing information, usually translated as “understanding” or “perception”.
חכמה is the function of contemplating information and mentally reacting to it, usually translated as “wisdom”.
דעת is thorough and complete knowledge of a subject.
It is occasionally used in the sense of having relations. This is because, if done correctly, intercourse allows each partner to gain intimate knowledge of their spouse’s essential person (i.e. their נשמה).
מדע is information; that which is known.
In ספר דניאל, it is used in the phrase וּמביני מַדָּע, meaning “understanders of [how to learn] information”.
שכל means regard or cleverness. It is the ability to make judgements about information.

I also agree with the questioneer, that the suggested words have been misused and some sources are using them with different definitions. In the sefer רדיפי מיא: שמות נרדפים, R. Yehuda Leib haLevi surveys many sources on this question on pages 43 - 48 and splits hairs regarding their meanings, some of which are rather murky. Personally I prefer using definitions from Malbim's sefer haCarmel, which have clear distinctions. I also like the points brought by R. Hersczeg in Patterns in Rashi, which discusses Rashi on Chumash and Gemara vs. Tosafos on Gemara in a clear fashion based on the teachings of R. Tzadok haCohen miLublin. He has a later and bigger sefer on this subject Darkhei Rashi.  By the way, R. Hersczeg authored the  Artscroll Rashi on Chumash and Feldheim Rashi on Tehilim.

חכמה - chokhmah.  According to Sefer haCarmel it represents any consideration to which two inherent opposite properties are applicable, one of wich is "wise" and another is "stupid". Chokhma applies to all events which we classify good/bad; character qualities such as love/hate; actions eating/fasting; kedusha/tumah, etc. In each of these matters, we understand that one mode of behavior would be called wise and another stupid. For example, overeating is stupid and proper eating is wise.

בינה - binah. According to the book by R. Hersczeg Patterns in Rashi and Malbim Sefer haCarmel, it represents ability to combine different sugios to identify correct common themes while rejecting incorrect ones. For example, the Tosafos commentary to the Gemara Bavli is written based on such a principle.

תבונה - t'vunah - a reason, which we can classify as true or false (related to bina).

דעה, דעת - deyah, da'as. According to the same books, it is the ability to note differences between sugios, even if they may discuss similar subjects. I.e. something that a person can perceive clearly, in a well-defined way. The Rashi's commentary on Talmud is written in such a style.

ידע - yad'a. According to Sefer haCarmel it is understanding built through examination from later events back to previous events. It can only be achieved through our senses based on conditions of time and place.

שׂכל - sekhel, According to sefer haCarmel it is ability to foresee later events from earlier events. It requires posessing strong analytic qualities of binah applied to things positioned in time and place according to relevant laws.



Is Malbim's sefer haCarmel you linked in English? or only in Hebrew?

@Phillip I only know of a Hebrew edition. I have not seen a translation.

so the sefer haCarmel is a lexicon in modern Hebrew for the Biblical Hebrew?

Correct, it's a lexicon of some words found in Malbim's commentaries. It's Hebrew is close to that of Mishna Berurah. Malbim wrote a commentary on the entire Tanakh so he was very careful and precise with word meanings. He died more than 20 yrs before Eliezer ben Yehuda made aliyah.
